# Blob is getting uploaded into different folder

Tags: azure-blob-storage

i have a storage account **customer**.
In that i have a container **voc**.
i created a folder in the container called **csvinput**.
When im uploading a file in to the folder **csvinput**, the file is getting uploaded in the container **voc** not in the folder **csvinput** inside the container.

It is actually uploading in the root folder not in subfolder

Any idea ho can we fix this

Comment: From you description, you seem try to upload blob on portal. I have try to upload using script, it seems no problem, but on portal I reproduce your problem, you can have a look of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with Azure portal; if you use script to upload blobs, there will be no problem.

I can reproduce your error. (But it only occurs on Azure portal. This seems a bug after update).

You need to do like this:

[image]

If I use Python code to upload, there will be no problem:

```
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__

connect_str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_name = "test"
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name,"csvinput/test.txt")

context = "This is a test."

blob_client.upload_blob(context)
```